# SQL Server 2008 R2 mirror performance

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, database-mirroring

We have a SQL Server 2008 R2 on production and failover server. Not setup as a cluster. 
There are about 30 databases consuming about 70GB disk space. Database files are growing at a steady rate, about 5GB a month.

Both servers have 48GB RAM, most of it dedicated to SQL Server.

Planning to setup mirroring between the production and fail-over server.

Are there performance issues with mirroring that we should be aware of? Will this slow down the query response time on production server?

Similar question with SQL Server 2012. Any experience with mirroring (via Always On) performance on SQL Server 2012?

Thank you
Abhi